# Dynamically reading app.settings in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, appsettings

I've moved my appsettings section outside of the web.config using:

```
   <appSettings configSource="AppSettings.config"/>
```

This allows me to change my appsettings without actually restarting IIS.

I know however, that IIS monitors all configuration files constantly. How can I attach to event my-appsetting-has-changed to take some custom action upon that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/multiple-config.aspx) and [this reference](http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx),

> [The] ASP.Net runtime does not detect when the external [config] file changes.

If that's true, then you might get some mileage out of the `FileSystemWatcher`, but I cannot think how to use that effectively in an ASP.NET scenario.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Write a windows service for the FileSystemWatcher. Using a FileSystemWatcher in ASP.net only shows that you do not understand what the lifecycle in ASP.net is like

Comment: Thanks, @citronas. That was, I had intended at least, my point about not being able to use it effectively in an ASP.NET scenario.

Comment: As not every ASP.NET hosting scenario makes installing a windows service an option, I hadn't recommended it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class for this.